# How to center horizontally the text area in the "tufte-book" class?

Tags: margins, geometry, tufte

In the following code, I want to center horizontally the text area (main body+margin area), but the `centering` option of the `geometry` package doesn't have any affects. **Is there a way to do this?**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,symmetric,showframe,centering]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document} 
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I know that something like `\PassOptionsToPackage{right=8.2cm}{geometry}` can do the job, but I think it should be there a logical way.

Comment: One of the main points in Tufte's style is *asymmetric* shape of the page.

Comment: @Sisabe: Then drop `Tufte` book

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence: No! I really love this class.

Comment: If you have such specific requirements, it may be a good moment to build your own class file that meets all the requirements

Comment: @Sisabe You can use the `\geometry` macro to override any geometry options you like in the preamble of your document. Just specify what you'd like to use for the left and right margins, text area, etc.

Comment: The tufte-book document class already loads the geometry package. So `\geometry{left=30mm, right=30mm}` solves your problem.